# Conditional chagngeDetectionStrategy in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a card component in Angular :

[image]

Please notice the rating stars , which is also a component.

However , in this particular case , the user can NOT tap the stars as it's a read only info.

(The same stars rating component is used in *other* components to actually set rate)

This is the decleration of the Stars component :

```
@Component({
    moduleId   : module.id,
    selector   : 'app-stars-rating',
    templateUrl: './stars.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./stars.component.scss'],
    providers  : [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
```

**Question:**

Looking at this :

```
 <Card col="1" row="2">
        <app-stars-rating [disabled]="true" [isSmall]="true">
        </app-stars-rating>
 </Card >
```

Is it possible to *conditionally* set `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` on the `app-stars-rating` component   ?

In other words :

```
<Card col="1" row="2">
        <app-stars-rating [isOnPush]="someVal" ...>
        </app-stars-rating>
 </Card >
```

Comment: What's the issue when you let it always as onpush? Should be fine

Comment: i don't think so, but you could have `ChangeDetectorRef` injected into your component and use it conditionally. ref: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

. It would be useful if you could describe what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @deezg Performance improvements. I know it's not that much but it's something

Comment: i see. i think `onPush` without `@Input` would do just fine. if you think about it, `onPush` is your best and most performant option. it cannot go lower than that. so  having `onPush` with additional logic (or `@Input`s) for edit enabled sounds liek a good approach. Even if you split view/edit in 2 separated components, your view one will still have at least `onPush`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to conditionally set **OnPush change detection** would be to [detach](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detach) the view from the **change detection tree** when editing is disabled.

```
public class StarsComponent {
  @Input() public disabled: boolean;

  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
     // Init
     if (this.disabled) {
       this.cdRef.detach();
     }
  }

  public refreshManual(): void {
     this.cdRef.detectChanges();     
  }
}
```

It will prevent change detection from running on your component until you **explicitly call** the `detectChanges()` method. If the component would then need to **enable** change detection again you can it add by calling the `reattach()` method.